# CMake not finding generator despite it being on the availble generator list

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I'm following along [this](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/) tutorial and I've finished the first step. When I used the gui version to try and compile it, I've run into a problem: it couldn't detect the generator from visual studio. I reinstalled Visual Studio and made a new project just to make sure that the generator is installed. After doing that, I checked if it detected it. I typed

```
cmake --help
```

into the console and it was written that 'Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64' was available as a generator. But when I set it to be the generator, I got the same error nevertheless.

This is the error message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  Generator

    Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64

  could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

And this is the 'Generators' section of 'cmake --help' command

```
Generators

The following generators are available on this platform:
  Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)

project (Test)

set (TEST_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (TEST_VERSION_MINOR 0)

configure_file ("$E:/programming/workspace/C++/Excercise/CMakeStuff/Test1/src/TestConfig.h.in""$E:/programming/workspace/C++/Excercise/CMakeStuff/Test1/bin/TestConfig.h")
include_directories("$E:/programming/workspace/C++/Excercise/CMakeStuff/Test1/bin")

add_executable (Test main.cpp)
```

Here's my main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "TestConfig.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stdout,"%s Version %d.%d\n", argv[0], TEST_VERSION_MAJOR, TEST_VERSION_MINOR);
        fprintf(stdout,"Usage: %s number\n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    double inputValue = atof(argv[1]);
    double outputValue = sqrt(inputValue);
    fprintf(stdout,"The square root of %g is %g\n", inputValue, outputValue);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you provide C code and `CMakeLists.txt` if they are not even processed because of the error? Instead, provide **exact error message** you got.

Comment: @Tsyvarev k gonna do it rn

Comment: Run CMake in Visual Studio Developer Prompt.

Comment: @arrowd The same error code as in the gui version, although I'm not sure if I did  the developer prompt correctly(it wasn't readily availble as a tool, so I had to add it).

Comment: [This bit of code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/ae153c691454ec24dbae5caa5d0e4bb2351d0886/Source/cmVSSetupHelper.cxx#L146) governs the detection of VS. It mentions several times that a reboot might be necessary after installation, so do that first. Next, you should see if the paths mentioned (all the `vcroot + ...` things) are present on your system. If all that is okay, there is a problem with the `ISetupInstance2` that VS is supposed to set up.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I am experiencing something very similar and unless I find a solution soon I'm going to reinstall VS2017.  I have tried all kinds of things and none of them is working.  All the tools are correctly installed, all the paths are setup, I have tried running in developer prompt, I have tried running as admin.  The latest update to VS2017 seems to have caused this problem on my machine.